# How to merge unstaging of files into local master branch?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I am working on a project where I use the master branch to only contain the various "release" worthy states (following the model here: https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

I have created a new branch for the last changes before the new release version, which includes unstaging some obsolete files (using `git rm --cached file1 file2` on the local release-branch). So at the current state, my local master branch is still tracking file1 and file2, while the local release branch is not.

How can I now merge the release branch into the local master, such that the local master adopts the unstaging (i.e. is no longer tracking the two files)? When I try to change to the master branch for the merge command, I get ">error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout".

To be clear, I do want to keep the files in my local directory. I just want Git to stop tracking them, so that when I push my local master to my remote, the files will be removed from the remote.

Answer (score 0):

To merge anything into `master`, you *must* check it out. But checking out `master` means syncing your worktree to the state of `master`, which means those two files must be overwritten to their current state in `master`. There are ways to "checkout" a branch without changing your local worktree, but you can't do those if you want to do a merge.

Solution:

1. `git stash -u` to stash away the untracked files
2. do your merge.
3. `git stash pop` to get them back.

Comment: @JonasKaminski did this answer your question?